# IE body width not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the body element set to 840px and then margins auto:

```
body {
width: 840px;
margin: auto;
}
```

on FF, safari, and chrome this centers everything in the body of my site. However on IE (testing in IE9 currently) all of my divs that are set to 100% still expand to the whole width of the screen. In dev tools it still says that the body has width 840 but it does not constrict the rest of the elements.

What to do here?

Comment: Is there anymore code you could divulge, as I did exactly what you put here, and it works fine for me, in IE7, 8 & 9. The only way that I got the result you explained is if the browser is in quirks mode, which may mean that there is something else causing the browser to go into quirks mode, like inconsistent markup or an incorrect doctype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use valid doctype like <!DOCTYPE HTML>

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<style>
body {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
}
</style>

<body>
SALALALLA
</body>
```

Comment: Don't forget to test this in IE8 and IE7 ...  Stylizing the BODY tag is a tricky business with IE, It's much more preferred to use a container DIV.

Comment: Use container of course, but doctype seems to be huge problem in the first place in my experience with IE and centering.

Answer (score 2):

IE doesn't support that ...  To do such you can create a master "container" div for IE only and use an IE specific CSS file (that mozilla etc will ignore, so that div will have no bearing on your current design) to set the width of the DIV and to center it using

```
#div_id{
width:840px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-420px;
}
```

Include the IE only css like such

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie8.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie7.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

Limited, yes, but IE doesn't allow for body width to be set.